# Unable to locate package libnginx-mod-http-lua

Tags: server, nginx, lua

I'm configuring a Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean and facing an issue. I've created a droplet with Ubuntu 16 server OS and installed Nginx. It is working fine! but I want to install LUA module for Nginx. For that I'm using following command.

```
sudo apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-lua
```

That gives me result as follows,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnginx-mod-http-lua
```

I'm new with Ubuntu, not sure I'm missing anything here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Ubuntu 16.04, but libnginx-mod-http-lua is in the default Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

Comment: I see, let me check with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: That's the best way to do it because libnginx-mod-http-lua from the **universe** repository depends on the version of Nginx that is in the 18.04 default repositories, so it's not compatible with the version of Nginx that you have currently installed in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help! however I'm facing issue with version 18.04 when I install MSSQL server on it. To solve that issue I used the older version!